# jQuery: How to time an element's fadeOut while still in loop?

Tags: jquery, css, loops

I am looping an element with opacity yet I would like to stop it after 4.8 sec after the document is loaded.  The snippet of my loop is here:

```
var centor = $(".centeror");
centor.delay(1000);
function centorRun(){
    centor.animate({opacity:'1'}, 700);
    centor.animate({opacity:'0.2'}, 700, centorRun);

}
centorRun();
```

Every time I run  `$(".centeror").delay(5800).fadeOut();` both out of function and in function scope I get bad results, and I'm thinking delay is not the function I should be using, am I right?

**PS** `centorRun` is within the `$("document").ready(function() {}`

Comment: so you want a flashing affect for 4.8 seconds?

Comment: Where's your loop?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?
Have you considered using setTimeout instead of delay()?

Comment: @Roysh Hi, i've tried it with  centor.setTimeout(5000); both within and outside of scope and it doesn't work, please let me know how this would work for you, thx.

Comment: you want the centoRun function to be delayed?

Comment: No, i've written it in the OP, so I would like it to completely dissappear after 5 sec.

Comment: You should try what @Firefrog has offered.
However, I don't see your loop

Comment: Ok check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggle 2 funciton every 2 seconds

```
$(".centeror").toggle(
  function() {
    $(this).animate({opacity:'.3'});
  }, function() {
    $(this).animate({opacity:'1'});
  }
);

setInterval(function(){$(".centeror").trigger('click')}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `setTimeOut` instead of delay. Something like `setTimeout(centorRun, 4800)`;

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  setTimeout('$(".centeror").fadeOut()',5000);
```

Change the time 5000 as mil Second what you like best. `1 sec=1000`